# Vue data() object Input v-model doesn't work unless I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

So this is incredibly hard to explain, instead I made a video to showcase what's going on:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=md0FWeRhVkE

To explain in steps:

- A user can create a new account.
- This user will be automatically logged in (no e-mail verification step yet).
- Then without refreshing the page, I'm trying to add a category.
- There's a custom  component that is v-modeled to a data() value (as you can see in the video this is category_name.
- Whenever I fill something in in the input field, this should display **above** the input field (as I'm dumping the value there). You see that this doesn't happen before the page refresh.
- However when I refresh the page, the v-model suddenly works.

Does anybody know what's going on and why it doesn't work when I register the user initially? It seems that the data() value `category_name` doesn't get created or something unless you refresh the page?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the files you show in the video, so we can try and reproduce the issue ourselves?

Comment: Sure here's the repo: https://github.com/Danielvandervelden/snippets fill in the env files. Run npm run serve in client and npm start in server. Make sure you create a database in mysql.

Comment: Have you tried setting an initial non-null value to `category_name` in the `data()`? Like `category_name: ''`

Comment: @Daniel - I'm unable to reproduce the problem you describe...it seems to work fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom input (`Input.vue`) is not declaring and using the `value` prop that `v-model` is binding to - see the docs how `v-model` on [custom component works](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)

> Wouldn't that only be necessary for two-way binding? As I see it, binding the value prop just allows the input value to be changed from the parent

Well, not exactly. `value` binding ("value from parent") is essential any time component is created **and** reused.

Reusing existing component instances is very common (and useful) optimization strategy Vue uses. You can play with the example below to see what is an effect of missing `value` biding on custom input.

And components are created more often then you can think. Switching to "Fixed" component and back demonstrates how broken the `v-model` without binding `value` is in case components are created dynamically (for example when used in Router views or some sort of custom "Tab" component)

I know this is "long shot" - I'm not sure this fixes the issue (sharing git repo doesn't fit to my definition of [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) **BUT** it is definitely a bug and I do not see anything else particularly wrong with the rest of the code...

Given how broken custom input without `value` is, it is reasonable to think that Vue devs never expected usage like this and that it can lead to all sorts of "strange" and unexpected behaviors ...

```js
Vue.component('my-input-broken', {
  props: ['name', 'type', 'label'],
  methods: {
    inputHandler(e) {
      this.$emit('input', e.target.value);
    },
  },
  template: `
  <div v-if="name && type" :id="name">
        <input v-if="type !== 'textarea'" @input="inputHandler" :name="name" :type="type" />
        <textarea v-else-if="type === 'textarea'" @input="inputHandler" @blur="blurHandler($event)" :name="name" type="textarea" />
        <label v-if="label" :for="name">{{label}}</label>
    </div>
  `
})

Vue.component('my-input-fixed', {
  props: ['name', 'type', 'label', 'value'],
  methods: {
    inputHandler(e) {
      this.$emit('input', e.target.value);
    },
  },
  template: `
  <div v-if="name && type" :id="name">
        <input v-if="type !== 'textarea'" @input="inputHandler" :name="name" :type="type" :value='value' />
        <textarea v-else-if="type === 'textarea'" @input="inputHandler" @blur="blurHandler($event)" :name="name" :value='value' type="textarea" />
        <label v-if="label" :for="name">{{label}}</label>
    </div>
  `
})

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      values: [""],
      componentToUse: 'a'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addInput() {
      this.values.unshift("")
    }
  },
  computed: {
    comp() {
      return this.componentToUse === 'a' ? "my-input-broken" : "my-input-fixed"
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <label for="componentToUse">Component to use:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="componentToUse" v-model="componentToUse" value="a"> Broken
  <input type="radio" name="componentToUse" v-model="componentToUse" value="b"> Fixed
  <hr>

  <button @click="addInput">Add at beginning...</button>
  <component :is="comp" v-for="(value, index) in values" :key="index" v-model="values[index]" :name="`value_${index}`" type="text" :label="`value_${index} ('${values[index]}')`"></component>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that only be necessary for two-way binding? As I see it, binding the value prop just allows the input value to be changed from the parent, but it doesn't seem make a difference in passing the data from the child component to the parent, which is handled by the `$emit`, unless that's just something required for `v-model` to function properly at all.

Comment: And you win. Thanks! Never knew I actually had to bind the value as well, since I assumed v-model did this.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, `v-model` binds into your custom component's `value` prop. But to make it work, you need to bind that `value` prop **inside your component** to a `value` attribute of the native `<input>` element. Check again the docs i'v linked and my example. Your last commit does not fix the issue....

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood the main problem of `v-model` now.

```
<input v-model="myObject[attribute]" />
```

is equivalent to

```
<input
  v-bind:value="myObject[attribute]"
  v-on:input="myObject[attribute] = $event"
  />
```

In my case the problem was that the GUI wasn't refreshing after `myObject[attribute]` was reassigned.

My workaround to this problem was to call `$forceUpdate()` after reassigning the variable which would look like following:

```
<input
  v-bind:value="myObject[attribute]"
  v-on:input="myObject[attribute] = $event; $forceUpdate()"
  />
```

Not sure if this solves your issue but I hope it helps somebody out there who is facing the same problem.